# </script> in PHP heredoc

Tags: php, javascript, heredoc

Why I am not able to end a javascript inside a PHP heredoc?

The rest of the code below this line:

```
</script>
```

become not part of PHP's code. They become HTML code.

It is like the end script code ends the PHP block.

```
$headerContent = <<<HEAD
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <title>$title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />

    <script>
    </script> // Here is the problem
    </head> // code here and below becomes not part of PHP.
    <body>
    .
    . 
    .
HEAD;
```

[image: screenshot for better view]

Any tips for solving this problem?

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: Is it the same *problem* [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T702GS) ?

Comment: @j0k doesn't look like there's a problem with that. Adding `htmlentities()` looks like it works. http://codepad.viper-7.com/blvIDG

Comment: Just as a tip – I used to love heredocs, but now I hate them with a passion. They are annoying for a number of reasons, but the main one for me is that they can't be indented – the start and end all have to be aligned to the left. This makes complex code very hard to work with. I often wish I could go back in time to warn my self not to use them!

Comment: @RichBradshaw Thanks for the tip. Since I had implemented heredocs, and my assignment now requires me to integrate javascript into my website, anyway to make it possible? Changing the whole code is very tedious.

Comment: Can't reproduce this with my PHP 5.4.

Comment: @Skydiver I can't in PHP 5.5 Alpha 6, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can't reproduce this with HEREDOC (it's possible that different versions of PHP behave differently in this respect), `</script>` is equivalent to `?>` in PHP code, because it's a counterpart to `<script language="php">`. Example:

```
<script language="php"> $a = 1; </script>
Test: <?= $a ?>
```

So wherever you encounter problems with the `?>` closing tag, you'll also encounter the same problems with the `</script>` closing tag. One option would be to store this in a variable and use it. Example:

```
<?php

$endScript = '</' . 'script>';
$headerContent = <<<HEAD
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <title>$title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />

    <script>
    $endScript
    </head>
    <body>
    .
    . 
    .
HEAD;
```

Comment: Thanks, so how am I able to add javascript into PHP's heredoc?

Comment: @BoonGǎgǎ, one idea would be to store `</script>` in a variable, like, for example, `$endScript = '</' . 'script>';` (just in case you have problems with `'</script>'` as well), then use `$endScript` instead of `</script>` inside the HEREDOC instance.